# Bootstrap nav-tabs not justified on multi-line case

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In Bootstrap `nav-tabs`, if one of my tabs has multiple lines, the other tabs don't get justified. How can I solve this problem (with pure CSS) so the height of all the tabs will be the same as the one with multiple line?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li>
        <a href="1.html">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="2.html">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="3.html">Tab 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="aa.html" class="active">Please open in "Full page" and change the window size if this is not multiline</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="5.html">Tab 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```